# Stop Chrome “restore previous session” function

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome-devtools

I am running chrome in kiosk mode. I had a background application that will kill chrome if the internet connection fails. When the connection is retored, it launches chrome again. However when it relaunched I have the “restore previous session” bubble show up. I don’t want it to do that. I want it to simply open up the startup pages that are defined in the startup settings.

Anyway to do this?

I know incognito mode does this but I need the cookies and passwords autocompletion on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do that is open "Preferences" file in path

"C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

and edit it modifing the entry:

- "exit_type":"none"
- "exited_cleanly":true

Save the file as read only.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi I couldn’t find “Default” within user data. I did find system profiler and then within that a file called preferences. I assume this willl Work?

Comment: I think yes but backup the original file before to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple user profiles, you may need to navigate to: 
"C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
(or whatever number) to get to your Preferences file.  You may have to do this for all the other profiles too, if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

here's a little bit of powershell I added to a script I have that kills and relaunches multiple chrome instances.  Works great but I changed `"exit_type":"Crashed"` to `"exit_type":"Normal"`.  All the usual caveats about using code from the internet at your own risk, YMMV, etc.

```
$c = Get-Content "$($env:localAppData)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
if ($c.IndexOf('"exit_type":"Crashed"') -gt 0) {
  Write-Information -MessageData "Chrome Crashed -- fooling startup to think it didn't"
  $c.Replace('"exit_type":"Crashed"', '"exit_type":"Normal"') | Set-Content "$($env:localAppData)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences" -NoNewLine
}
```

Answer (score -1):

very simple use `--incognito` in chrome startup properties

Comment: Did you recognize that the questionner knows about incognito mode but needs more?